# CSS3 webkit-progress-bar animate background-position

Tags: html, css, webkit, blink

I am looking for a working solution, to **animate** the `background-position` property of an [html5](/questions/tagged/html5) [progress](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/progress) element in [webkit](/questions/tagged/webkit)/[blink](/questions/tagged/blink).

HTML:

```
<progress max="100" value="0"></progress>
```

CSS:

```
progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
  -webkit-animation: moveBackground 2s steps(30) infinite;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, orange 50%, blue 100%);
  background-size: 30rem;
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveBackground
{
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -50rem 0;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6gekeegg/

However, [gecko](/questions/tagged/gecko) supports the animation of the `background-position` property, simple example:

```
progress[value] {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: 11. Mar. 2015:**

[chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) `<=41` seems not to support animations for the `background-position` attribute of progress elements.

I have created a working solution with the `::after` [css](/questions/tagged/css) pseudo-element:

> https://jsfiddle.net/x7urfdev/

**Please note:** [[image]firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) does not support the `::after` or `::before` pseudo-elements on progress elements.

Comment: It's a regression. It works ok in Chrome 40, but not in 41 or 42 (Canary)

Answer (score 0):

animation property should be prefixed

```
-webkit-animation: moveBackground 2s steps(30) infinite;
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t0uz81k6/1/)

Comment: I've tested your fiddle in Windows 7+8 - no, but it does not work (animation).